# Missing `server' JVM (Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll.)

Tags: java, dll, jvm

Getting [JVM](https://java.com) *error* that it is missing some *dll*.

Comment: you need to install jdk , you are trying with jre

Comment: Hi, can you please check my related post ? thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639088/neo4j-3-0-7-enterprise-trial-version-failed-to-start-in-windows

Answer (score 137, accepted):

To Fix The "*Missing "server"* JVM at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm­­.dll`, please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.

Follow these steps:

Go to oracle.com and install Java JRE7 (Check if Java 6 is not installed already)

After that, go to `C:/Program files/java/jre7/bin`

Here, create an folder called `Server`

Now go into the `C:/Program files/java/jre7/bin/client` folder

Copy all the data in this folder into the new `C:/Program files/java/jre7/bin/Server` folder

Comment: That fixes the error message but doesn't provide a server JRE.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html

Comment: I wanted a hack to fix neo4j 3.0.0 Error: missing `server' JVM jvm.dll.  The new server folder fixed the error and allowed me to run neo4j without additional effort. So I can fix the server JRE at a later date as per sourcedelica but I have a low impedance fix to get moving. Hence, my plus one vote.

Comment: Worked for me for Apache MINA SSHD and JRE 1.8.0_131. Thx, you saved my day!

Comment: this quick fix approach help me repaiiring sqlanywhere 11.0.1.2506 by adapting to a different path required for that. Since I don't need the java in day to day work. I will skip neo4j proper way. and remove all java from the system reduce risk surface

Comment: worked for me to fix an apache zookeeper server run

Comment: For me, this also worked by just creating a junction: `mklink /J server client` . The folder isn't very big so it won't matter too much either way but some of you may prefer this approach.

Comment: I don't have permissions for creating such folder under C:\ drive , is there any solution?

Comment: This does fix the Missing Server error (thanks!) BUT make sure you have Java JRE installed from Oracle.com (installation should include a "server" folder without "client" folder inside the /java/jre folder)