# Files\Java\jjre1.8.0_51\bin\server\jvm.dll file is missing

Tags: java, jvm

happens when I try to run Mods on Crazy Craft for Minecraft. Tried their support and no response or solution.

comes up with

> Error: missing 'server' JVM at 'C;\Program
>   Files\Java\jjre1.8.0_51\bin\server\jvm.dll' PLease install or use the
>   JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.

I've attempted to download several versions of Java and install them but to no success. Anyway can I code it in or download it from another Java?

Comment: I'm going to assume that, for whatever reason, you hand-typed that error message rather than copy-and-paste, because there are several things very wrong with that path (the semi-colon and the double-j). Anyway. Does that file actually exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18123162/5068532
watch at this link it'll show you what to do