# Cannot install elasticsearch 5.1.1 on windows 10 with java 8

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8

I am attempting to install ElasticSearch 5.1.1 on my windows 10 's laptop with java 8.111 installed.

when I try to install Elastic search that triggers an error

C:\Users\userName\Downloads\elasticsearch-5.1.1\elasticsearch-5.1.1>.\bin\elasticsearch

Displays me that error message  :

```
Error: missing `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
```

I found a [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123144/missing-server-jvm-java-jre7-bin-server-jvm-dll) for that type of error with java . That consist in creating a folder server and to copy paste jvm.dll into. 
But it should be avalaible for java 7 cause if I try that fix and I launch the installation again I have now the error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

[image]

If has no sens cause I have 8 go of RAM

Do you have idea about what I should do to install ElasticSearch?

Comment: I don't know if it's still the same on W10 but did you run the installation as "Administrator" ?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: Not sure but it looks like configuration issue of JVM which can't allocate 2G (1024*1024*2 KB exactly). How much RAM do you have ?

Comment: thank for answere : I have 8 GO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto config folder and open `elasticsearch.yml` file then do below changes.

Uncomment the `cluster.name` and `node.name` in `elasticsearch.yml` like below and give your own cluster and node name.

```
cluster.name: ESCluster

node.name: ESNode
```

Change heap size in `jvm.options`

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

Goto bin folder then run `elasticsearch.bat`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check if the Java software that you install is 64bit(on 64bit machine).
When you install "elasticsearch" on 64bit Windows machine, it searches for 64bit Java on the computer, and when you install Java, by default, you install 32 bit Java.

Answer (score 0):

I made/confirmed the suggested configs.

I confirmed 64bit java:

`$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)`

`>elasticsearch-5.4.3\bin>elasticsearch.bat`

`Error: encountered environment variables that are no longer supported
Use jvm.options or ES_JAVA_OPTS to configure the JVM
ES_MIN_MEM=100000: set -Xms100000 in jvm.options or add "-Xms100000" to ES_JAVA_OPTS
ES_MAX_MEM=900000: set -Xmx900000 in jvm.options or add "-Xmx900000" to ES_JAVA_OPTS`