# Install Elasticsearch Service in Windows

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

Elasticsearch service can not install in windows, When I run blow command:

```
.\elasticsearch-service.bat install
```

This output displayed in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Norman\Desktop\elasticsearch\bin>.\elasticsearch-service.bat install
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
'findstr /b \- "C:\Users\Norman\Desktop\elasticsearch\config\jvm.options" | findstr /b /v "\-server \-client"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: https://efficientuser.wordpress.com/2016/11/01/installing-elasticsearch-5-0-as-service-on-windows/

Comment: I hope this will resolve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145921/canot-install-elasticsearch-5-1-1-on-windows-10-with-java-8/41157125#41157125

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canot install elasticsearch 5.1.1 on windows 10 with java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145921/canot-install-elasticsearch-5-1-1-on-windows-10-with-java-8)

Comment: This question is not duplicate.