# java -version returns missing `server' JVM at `jre1.8/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so'

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

Not sure if I did this correctly but on our linux server, java 1.6 is installed. I created a shell script that executes a jar file that needs to run on java 1.8 so I download jre1.8.zip from Oracle and extracted (/tmp/jre1.8) this in a folder in the linux machine.

When I try to test by executing a simple /tmp/jre1.8/bin/java -version command, I get the following error:

Error: missing `server' JVM at`jre1.8/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so'.

Is there anyway I can get this to work with root privilege?

Comment: this any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123144/missing-server-jvm-java-jre7-bin-server-jvm-dll

Comment: “jre1.8.zip from Oracle”? Which download is that? I can’t see such a download on Oracle’s official download pages.

Comment: @Holger don't mind the file name. i renamed it to that. here's the link where i downloaded it. https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=238717_478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab

Comment: So it’s a `.tar.gz` rather than `.zip`, which is relevant for the file attributes. Since the attributes are not the problem, perhaps, there’s a system policy not to execute binary code from `/tmp`?

Comment: @Holger apparently the jre that i downloaded doesn't seem to work so i downloaded another version (1.8.0_202). i then extracted this and it seemed to work.